# Syntax highlighting and indentation not working at the end of a specific file in python-mode

Tags: python

At the end of one of my files for loops stop being highlighted, aren't automatically indented when I enter them, and <kbd>TAB</kbd> won't indent four spaces either. I don't have this issue in any other of my python buffers.  How do I figure out what's wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Comment out or remove  everything but the offending lines.  If the problem goes away, recursively bisect the rest of the file to isolate the problem.

Comment: I finally spotted a syntax error in the previous line. Please post your comment in answer form so I can accept it; I would like to know more about how you would recursively bisect a file in Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If syntax highlighting or indentation suddenly stops working as
expected at some point in your buffer/file, there's a very good
chance you have a syntax error somewhere above it.

In these situations, the most straightforward way to identify the
offending lines is to bisect your buffer/file recursively.  What
that means is to comment out all the material above the lines that
are giving you problems.  Uncomment one half.  If the problem
comes back, the error is probably somewhere in that half.  Repeat
the procedure in the offending half by uncommenting one half of
the half until you isolate the error.

Note that this procedure is a common remedy for a problems in your
init file, but the principle is similar for any source code.